# What comes first .always() or .then() callbacks in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred, deferred-execution

If you have a function which has both `.then` and `.always` callbacks, which one will get executed first?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see, I'm guessing `then()`

Comment: And I just did, took one minute, and I was right -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ou1sy6uw/**

Comment: However, swapping them, they return differently -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ou1sy6uw/1/**, so whatever order they are added

Comment: The best would be to not rely on the order. Single threaded JS by default is protected from concurrency issues, if only we don't do silly things in our code.

Comment: OP, please rephrase your title to be more specific...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from the [`deferred.resolve()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) documentation:

> When the Deferred is resolved, any doneCallbacks added by
>   deferred.then() or deferred.done() are called. Callbacks are executed
>   in the order they were added.

Example below:

```js
var $logger = $("#logEntry");
function addLog(content){
   $logger.append($("<li/>").html(content));
}

var newPromise = $.Deferred();

$.when(newPromise).done(function() {
    addLog("1st $when().done!");
});

newPromise.then(function() {
    addLog("1st then!");
}).always(function() {
    addLog("1st always!");
}).done(function() {
    addLog("1st done!");
}).done(function() {
    addLog("2nd done!");
}).always(function() {
    addLog("2nd always!");
}).then(function() {
    addLog("2nd then!");
});

$.when(newPromise).done(function() {
    addLog("2nd $when().done!");
});

addLog("Resolving promise!");

newPromise.resolve();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="logEntry"></ul>
```

Comment: In your example `always` is attached to `then`, which is a bit different from what OP asked.